# Updating products with fetch and input value fields

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have spent whole day trying to figure this out. I want to update course recipes from my database (MongoDB) using my REST API call (Node.js with Express) by sumbiting input fields with new values of the recipe. I tried to show previous values by using input value="", but as I learned this makes it to be static. I tried to change it into dynamic accordingly to what I found online however none of tutorials I found would show what I am looking for. As you can see in code below I am trying to PUT new data that was previously set using setState(). Sadly I do not know how can I do it like this. Could you tell me if it is even possible and if so where can I learn to do it?

Here is code from React:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Alert from "../elements/Alert";
import Axios from "axios";

export default function UpdateCourse() {
  const id = window.location.href.split("?")[1];

  const [dishName, setdishName] = useState("");
  const [category, setcategory] = useState("");
  const [author, setauthor] = useState("");
  const [ingredients, setingredients] = useState([]);
  const [cookingTime, setcookingTime] = useState("");
  const [sourceUrl, setsourceUrl] = useState("");
  const [imageUrl, setimageUrl] = useState("");
  const [isPublished, setisPublished] = useState("true");
  const [price, setprice] = useState("");
  const [tags, settags] = useState([]);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const url = `http://localhost:1234/api/courses/find/${id}`;

  const old = async () => {
    const result = await Axios.get(url);
    setdishName(result.data.dishName);
    setcategory(result.data.category);
    setauthor(result.data.author);
    setingredients(result.data.ingredients);
    setcookingTime(result.data.cookingTime);
    setsourceUrl(result.data.sourceUrl);
    setimageUrl(result.data.imageUrl);
    setisPublished(result.data.isPublished);
    setprice(result.data.price);
    settags(result.data.tags);
  };
  old();
  console.log(old);

  async function update() {
    let item = {
      dishName,
      category,
      author,
      ingredients,
      cookingTime,
      sourceUrl,
      imageUrl,
      isPublished,
      price,
      tags,
    };

    console.log(item);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(item));

    const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:1234/api/courses/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (result.status !== 200) {
      return setAlert(result.status + " " + result.statusText);
    }

    history.push("/");
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-sm-6" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h1 className="bigBar">Update recipe</h1>
      <div style={{ marginLeft: "3.5rem" }}>
        {alert !== "" && <Alert alert={alert}></Alert>}
      </div>
      <input
        autoFocus="autofocus"
        required="required"
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder={dishName}
        value={dishName}
        onChange={e => setdishName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />

      <input
        required="required"
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder={category}
        value={category}
        onChange={e => setcategory(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setauthor(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        required="required"
        placeholder={author}
        value={author}
      />
      <br />

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setingredients(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        required="required"
        placeholder={ingredients}
        value={ingredients}
      />

      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setcookingTime(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        required="required"
        placeholder={cookingTime}
        value={cookingTime}
      />
      <br />

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setsourceUrl(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        required="required"
        placeholder={sourceUrl}
        value={sourceUrl}
      />
      <br />

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setimageUrl(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        required="required"
        placeholder={imageUrl}
        value={imageUrl}
      />
      <br />

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setisPublished(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        required="required"
        placeholder={isPublished}
        value={isPublished}
      />
      <br />

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => setprice(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        required="required"
        placeholder={price}
        value={price}
      />
      <br />

      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => settags(e.target.value)}
        className="form-control"
        required="required"
        placeholder={tags}
        value={tags}
      />
      <br />

      <button onClick={update} className="btn btn-primary">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is put from REST API:

```
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validateCourse(req.body);
  if (error)
    //400 Bad request
    return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const course = await Course.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    _.pick(req.body, [
      `dishName`,
      `category`,
      `password`,
      `ingredients`,
      `cookingTime`,
      `sourceUrl`,
      `imageUrl`,
      `isPublished`,
      `price`,
      `tags`,
    ]),
    {
      useFindAndModify: false,
      new: true,
    }
  );

  if (!course)
    return res.status(404).send(`The course with the given ID was not found`);

  res.send(course);
});
```

And here is sample course from MongoDB:

```
{
    "isPublished": true,
    "tags": [
        "pizza"
    ],
    "_id": "60ae108ddfb18463c046a5ba",
    "dishName": "Pizza with Cauliflower Crust",
    "category": "pizza",
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c18517606",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit": "",
            "description": "medium head cauliflower cut into florets"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c18517607",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit": "",
            "description": "egg"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c18517608",
            "quantity": 0.5,
            "unit": "cup",
            "description": "mozzarella shredded"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c18517609",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit": "tsp",
            "description": "oregano or italian seasoning blend"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c1851760a",
            "quantity": null,
            "unit": "",
            "description": "Salt and pepper to taste"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c1851760b",
            "quantity": 1,
            "unit": "cup",
            "description": "chicken cooked and shredded"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c1851760c",
            "quantity": 0.5,
            "unit": "cup",
            "description": "barbecue sauce"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c1851760d",
            "quantity": 0.75,
            "unit": "cup",
            "description": "mozzarella shredded"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c1851760e",
            "quantity": null,
            "unit": "",
            "description": "Red onion to taste thinly sliced"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60a4cfa48c20aa5c1851760f",
            "quantity": null,
            "unit": "",
            "description": "Fresh cilantro to taste"
        }
    ],
    "cookingTime": 60,
    "sourceUrl": "https://www.closetcooking.com/cauliflower-pizza-crust-with-bbq/",
    "imageUrl": "https://www.closetcooking.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/BBQ-Chicken-Pizza-with-Cauliflower-Crust-500-4699.jpg",
    "price": 29.99,
    "date": "2021-05-26T09:10:37.620Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

[image: Here is how it looks like]

Comment: I dont know if i understood correctly so please correct me if im wrong. After user has updated some values and clicked submit - the request is sent to backend to update database - now you reload the page and you want the input values to include the updated values rather than the old (before submitting) , no?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want. I also wanted to include old values shown in input fields so user can see what was there before and he wouldn't have to type the whole thing anew, but instead just change theese values. Unluckilly when I put that old value hich user might want to correct it becomes static and I was unable to figure out how to change it into dynamic (I searched web for an answer but all tutorials didn't work in my case or at least I was not smart enought to include them)

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me if that worked for you

Comment: Thank you for response, but sadly I think you missunderstood me, I am adding a screen shot of how the app looks like to make it easier. Fetching data from API works, at least most of it. Sadly because ingredients is a table of objects I am unable to fetch it properly (as shown on picture above). Also I cannot change values in any of theese fields because I am setting values of inputs. Theese are my questions: How can I show ingredients properly and how can I change inputs so despite using custom values they are not static but dynamic instead

Comment: Basically I would like the user to be able to change values in theese inputs in order to update recipe. I know I can use placeholders instead of value but then the user will have to type the whole thing himself (and in case of ingredients it is pretty long). It seems to me that showing in inputs current data (old) so he can simply change what he likes is more user-friendly. I know that ingredients field look terrible, I was thinking of how can I make it easier for user to fill but since it is a table of objects I didn't think of any other way to pass values to it. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I added a sample project that helps you show and edit ingredients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When button is clicked and the PUT request is made and the values are updated - you must also tell your component states to mirror the new changes ***from the backend.***

Therefor you must call old() method (which handles the fetching request and set states) ***after*** your PUT request. This is makes sure that your component states is sync with the values from the database.

Here is a small modification to your update() method (I marked it with an arrow):

```js
async function update() {
    let item = {
      dishName,
      category,
      author,
      ingredients,
      cookingTime,
      sourceUrl,
      imageUrl,
      isPublished,
      price,
      tags,
    };

    console.log(item);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(item));

    const result = await fetch(`http://localhost:1234/api/courses/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (result.status !== 200) {
      return setAlert(result.status + " " + result.statusText);
    }

    history.push("/");
    window.location.reload();

    old() <----- THIS

  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I made a small example in Codesandbox that help you display ***ingredients*** and change their values.

I havent used any UI libraries but i strongly recommend something like Material UI to implement the containers and display them in a more proper way -it is all up to you how you want to design it.

Well here is it: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-sammet-d8wq5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This seems to almost solve my question. Sadly I found only one problem with this solution. Since ingredients are rendered after data is fetched from API the function that sets all starting values is working indefinietly. I placed simple console.log to test this and it seems that if I call start function then site crashes after printing this cl 1000 times. Function I am talking about is `old()`. I tried tcalling it in different places but every time it would repeat itself until site crashes.

Comment: Call it inside a useEffect with an empty dependancy. That should only fetch once when component mounts.

Comment: You are the best man! Thank you so so much :D